# In UNIX file, quickly sort each line's fields (columns)

Tags: unix

I have a file that looks like this

```
12;6
2;4
9;4
...
```

In this case the field (column) delimiter is a ";". I want to sort the fields in each line.  An acceptable output would be:

```
6;12
2;4
4;9
```

An acceptable solution can assume that the field delimiter is a ";" and the values are integers.  An ideal solution is more flexible, allowing different delimiters and for alphanumeric sorting.

This all needs to be done on the command line.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -wne '$,=";"; chop; 
    print sort { $a <=> $b } split ";";
    print "\n"' input
```

If your perl isn't ancient:

```
perl -wnE '$,=";"; chop; 
        say sort { $a <=> $b } split ";"' input
```

You can also do:

```
perl -F\; -wanE 'chop $F[-1]; $,=";"; say sort { $a <=> $b } @F' input
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution (over some others) is that it works even if there a three or more fields on the line too.

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{if($1>$2)print $2,$1;else print $1,$2;}' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  cat t.txt
12;6
2;4
9;4
ccc;aaa
bab;baa

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{if($1>$2)print $2,$1;else print $1,$2;}' t.txt
6;12
2;4
4;9
aaa;ccc
baa;bab
```

Comment: Why not `-F';'` on the command line, avoiding the verbose BEGIN block?